# Calculating bytes returned from read operation

Tags: c, debugging, unix, gdb

I have a program that reads from STDIO_FILENO. The input source is a txt file which contains ***15 integers***. After calling read and storing the returned value in ***n***. I inspect it with gdb *print n*. Gdb tells me that read returned 45 bytes. I was expecting **60 bytes based on (32bit x 15) / 8**. Can someone explain to me where I'm making the bad calculation.

```
#define BUFFSIZE 4096

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int n;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];

    while((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE)) > 0)
        if(write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n) != n)
            err_sys("write error");

    if(n < 0)
        err_sys("read error");

    exit(0);
}


Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbffb38) at stdin_stdout.c:10
10      while((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE)) > 0)
(gdb) print n
$1 = 0
(gdb) n

Breakpoint 2, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbffb38) at stdin_stdout.c:11
11          if(write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n) != n)
(gdb) print n
$2 = 45
```

Comment: I thought you said it was a text file. If so, where does "32bit" come from?

Comment: Also, to be very, very precise, if it's a text file, it contains digits and spaces, not integers. While fifteen is an integer, a text file that contains "15" contains two symbols, a "1" digit followed by a "5" digit. It doesn't really contain the integer fifteen, but two digits that can be interpreted as the number fifteen if interpreted as decimal.

Comment: I would think from the integers in the file? This example is from a UNIX programming book I'm studying.

Comment: Is it a text file or a file containing multi-byte integers?

Comment: There's a different between the integer fifteen and the digit "1" followed by the digit "5". One is an integer and the other is two symbols that can be interpreted as an integer if you decide to interpret them in base 10.

Comment: Its a file containing integers. multi-byte? The file has 15 integers each on a newline

Comment: If it's a text file, it doesn't have 15 integers. It has text. "12 32" is not the integer twelve and the integer thirty two. It's the symbol "1", the symbol "2", a space, the symbol "3" and the symbol "2". Text files don't contain integers, they contain text symobls.

Comment: okay thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: so where does the 45 bytes come from that read returns? How do i calculate that?

Comment: Presumably there are 45 bytes of text in the text file. Maybe each integer is two characters. So for 15 integers, that's 30 characters plus 15 newlines, gives 45.

Comment: David thats awesome thanks for expounding on this topic. Really appreciated. The file system does show the size of my source file as 45 bytes. Each integer is two characters plus the 15 newline as you pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing numbers with representations of numbers. Since this is a text file, it contains text, not integers.

You can, for example, convert the text "12 32" into the integer twelve and the integer thirty-two, but you have to do it. You have to use base 10 and you have to agree that a space separates integers. The text will be five bytes if each character is one byte. You can then convert it into 8 bytes (two 32-bit integers) if you want. But that conversion has to actually be done, it doesn't do itself.